# Why won't resultSet.next() advance when there's clearly more data?

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc

So I'm having trouble understanding why a resultSet from an executed query will not continue to advance when there's clearly more entries to iterate over. I have a table called all_projects, and when I run this query:

```
SELECT project_title, created_date, isActive FROM all_projects WHERE project_lead='myUser' ORDER BY created_date DESC;
```

in my PSQL shell, this is the result I get:

[image]

The column data types are: String, Timestamp, and Boolean.

I'm attempting to get each row, create an Array[String] from it, to create, ultimately, a list of an array of strings ( `List[Array[String]]` )

When I iterate over this with resultSet.next(), it is able to retrieve the first two values, but then when I call next after acquiring the first timestamp value, it fails and returns false.

Below is my code - riddled with a lot of println debug statements to see what happens, stack/and print trace will be at the bottom.

```
 def getAll(userName: String, db: Database): List[Array[String]] = {
    val tablesQuery = s"SELECT project_title, created_date, isActive FROM all_projects WHERE project_lead=? ORDER BY created_date DESC;"
    var returnResult = new ListBuffer[Array[String]]
    db.withConnection { conn =>
      val ps = conn.prepareStatement(tablesQuery)
      ps.setString(1, userName)
      val qryResult = ps.executeQuery()
      val columnCount = qryResult.getMetaData.getColumnCount
      println("RETRIEVED THIS MANY COLUMNS: " + columnCount)
      while (qryResult.next()) {
        println("Achieved next in while loop >>>>>>>>>>>")
        val row = new Array[String](columnCount)
        for (i <- 0 to columnCount - 1) {
          println(s"Inserting into Array($i) from the column index(${i + 1})")
          if (i < 2) {
            println("Tried to get string: ");
            row(i) = qryResult.getString(i + 1)
          } else { // note I also just tried to keep it all as .getString()
            println("Tried to get boolean: ");
            row(i) = qryResult.getBoolean(i+1).toString
          } // retrieve by column index SQL columns start at 1
          println("Row before we move on: " + row.mkString(", "))
          if (i <= columnCount - 2) {
            println("Called next? -> " + qryResult.next())
          }
        }
        returnResult += row
      }
    }
    returnResult.toList
  }
```

And here is the resulting print stack, which should have been fine, but as you can see, returns `false` when attempting `next()` when the cursor is on the first timestamp value.

```
THIS MANY COLUMNS: 3
Achieved next in while loop >>>>>>>>>>>
Inserting into Array(0) from the column index(1)
Tried to get string: 
Row before we move on: Wild Elephants of Mexico, null, null
Called next? -> true
Inserting into Array(1) from the column index(2)
Tried to get string: 
Row before we move on: Wild Elephants of Mexico, 2017-08-05 11:00:44.078232, null
Called next? -> false
Inserting into Array(2) from the column index(3)
Tried to get boolean: 
[error] o.j.ResultSetLogger - java.sql.ResultSet.getBoolean: 
throws exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Would rather use [Anorm](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/)

Comment: You are calling **qryResult.next()** inside for loop again while comparing value of **i** with **column length** so in for loop you move to next row in result set. So you miss out on row because again while calls **qryResult.next()**. May be check your logic and use only one **qryResult.next()**

Comment: `next()` moves to the next **row**, not to the next **column**, you should not call `next()` inside your while loop, because it will make you skip rows. You should already have noticed this as your output shows that you print the title of the **first row** with the timestamp of the **second row**...

Comment: Oh, oh god. I thought next() just went to the next value. As in, left to right through the cells. Everything makes so much more sense.

Comment: Java has pretty thorough documentation. I can recommend to actually read the API doc of Java, especially if things aren't behaving as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `qryResult.next()` within what you mean to be the handling of a single row, breaking everything. (Boy are you making your life much too difficult.)

A `ResultSet` represents a query result as a movable pointer to a single row of the query result. You handle rows one at a time, and then call `next()` **only when you have fully completed handling of that row**.

Let's make things much much simpler. (I'm just writing this out in a web page, don't have time to check or compile it, so please excuse my boo-boos.)

```
def handleRow( qryResult : ResultSet, columnCount : Int ) : Array[String] = {
   (1 to columnCount).map( i => qryResult.getString(i) ).toArray
}

def getAll(userName: String, db: Database): List[Array[String]] = {
  val tablesQuery = s"SELECT project_title, created_date, isActive FROM all_projects WHERE project_lead=? ORDER BY created_date DESC;"
  db.withConnection { conn =>
    val ps = conn.prepareStatement(tablesQuery)
    ps.setString(1, userName)
    val qryResult = ps.executeQuery()
    val columnCount = qryResult.getMetaData.getColumnCount
    println("RETRIEVED THIS MANY COLUMNS: " + columnCount)
    var buffer = new ListBuffer[Array[String]]
    while (qryResult.next()) {
      buffer += handleRow( qryResult, columnCount )
    }
    buffer.toList
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops! Initially I put `(1 until columnCount)` what should have been `(1 to columnCount)`, which would have left you one column short. Sorry!